# Mongoose include fields from a secondary document using $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lookup

I want to display all of the locations and attach orders (if there are any) to the response.

Locations document example:

```
{
  id: "LOCATION_A_OBJECTID",
  name: "Location A"
},
{
  id: "LOCATION_B_OBJECTID",
  name: "Location B"
},
{
  id: "LOCATION_C_OBJECTID",
  name: "Location C"
}
```

Orders document example:
(2 orders to A, 1 order to B, 0 orders to C)

```
{
  id: "5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d",
  location: "LOCATION_A_OBJECTID", 
  products: [1,2,3]
},
{
  id: "5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d",
  name: "LOCATION_B_OBJECTID",
  products: [1,2,3]
},
{
  id: "5e17a001f1e0220def7a2b5d",
  name: "LOCATION_A_OBJECTID",
  products: [1,2,3]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
  id: "LOCATION_A_OBJECTID",
  name: ...
  products: ...
   ...
},
{
  id: "LOCATION_B_OBJECTID",
  name: ...
  products: ...
  ...
}
...
```

**Edit**
Will post my schemas here because something is just not right.

Order Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
  },
  timestamp: {
    type: Date, default: Date.now
  },
  status: Number,
  products: Array,
  total:   Number
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
```

Location Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const locationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  address: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema)
```

Comment: Should `products` for `A` be `[1,2,3]` or `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` ?

Comment: @mickl products should be an array of arrays. `[1,2,3],[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to match against `name` or `location` field and then simply you can run `$project` to get desired format of your result documents:

```
db.Locations.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Orders",
            let: { loc_id: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                { $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ "$$loc_id", "$_id" ] } } },
                { $project: { _id: 0, products: 1 } }
            ],
            as: "orders"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { orders: { $ne: [] } }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            products: "$orders.products"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sl3b47CBDNb)

Comment: something is not working @mickl, note that inside `orders` document, `location` is populated with ObjectId. I get empty arrays in the `products` key. Using exactly your code except `match` (because it gives me 0 locations for some reason)

Comment: shouldn't matter if you have same ObjectIds on both sides. You need to convert if types are different otherwise

Comment: notice that the result in the mango playground isn't returning all locations. Only those with orders. What i want is - display all locations, and if there are any orders - attach them to the proper location in the response. Removing `match` solves this (locations with no orders are ok)

Comment: @Dor please just remove `$match` stage to include those with empty `orders`

Comment: I have the same Object Ids on both sides

Comment: @Dor could you build another Mongo Playground with some of your actual values. My solution was built based on the documents you provided. If actual data is different then you need to find the difference

Comment: that took some time but I made it! It's almost an exact reflection of my db. https://mongoplayground.net/p/6BFjy5elABg

Comment: @Dor modified my answer and the playground

Comment: It's working on Playground, not on my environment :( I get the locations but with empty arrays inside. I certainly have orders. I use MongoDB Cloud. Does it have to do with my Schemas? Modifying my main thread with the schemas.

Comment: @Dor try to verify `from: "Orders",` part. Is that the name of your collection ?

Comment: oh my god i'm literally speechless. I tried "Orders" at first and then I realized it's the not name of my Schema ("Order") but when that failed too, I started smashing my head. oh gosh. Thank you, thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, you completely did more than you should. but I wanted to ask you if it would be easy to get the amount of total orders for each location + the amount of orders. (So now I know the right way would be to use `$project` and add two keys: `total` and `amount` for each location)

Comment: @Dor I think so but to avoid confusion you should probably open a new question and provide your data with expected output. You can link it here, I will try to take a look later if noone else answers

Comment: Thanks! will do so.

Comment: Started a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59723160/get-the-total-amount-of-aggregated-data-in-mongoose